# ZFS on Linux (RHEL 7.5) ls: reading directory .: Not a directory

Tags: rhel, zfs

We have a Linux server that is running ZFS on Linux 0.7.8 and RHEL 7.5.  The /home filesystem is ZFS.  It was working fine until users reported that the filesystem was not accessible.

Zpool show the state is healthy.  A scrub did not reveal any errors.  The filesystem mounts and unmounts without errors.  The % disk used looks fine.  But you cannot get any ls to work, for example, cd /home then ls shows this error:

`ls: reading directory .: Not a directory`

Has anyone seen this before and know how to deal with it?  What other information would you like to see?  Thanks!

```
$ zpool list home  
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT  
home   928G  80.2G   848G         -     1%     8%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Comment: Also, I checked to see which modules were loaded:
zfs                  3559329  0
zunicode              331170  1 zfs
zavl                   15236  1 zfs
icp                   270187  1 zfs
zcommon                73440  1 zfs
znvpair                89131  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   102412  4 icp,zfs,zcommon,znvpair

Comment: Does `dmesg` say anything helpful?

Comment: And this question got downovted because... Can the troll please come back and complete the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to backported changes Red Hat made in the 7.5 kernel (v3.10.0-862). `ls` makes the `getdents()` system call, which now does  `iterate_dir()` instead of `readdir()`.

Reverting to kernel v3.10.0-693.21.1 should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reverting to the latest z-stream kernel of 7.4, I rebuilt the latest packages available (0.7.8) with the patch from the ZoL developers that fixes the issue.
I've uploaded all of my rpms here:
https://step.polymtl.ca/~coyote/dist/zfs/0.7.8-1.2

Answer (score 0):

zfs 0.7.9 is now available in the repos which fix the issue.